# What security issues come from calling methods with reflection?

Tags: java, json

I'm working on a project that has hosts and clients, and where hosts can send commands to clients (via sockets).

I'm determined that using JSON to communicate works the best.

For example:

```
{
    "method" : "toasty",
    "params" : ["hello world", true]
}
```

In this example, when this JSON string is sent to the client, it will be processed and a suitable method within the client will be run as such:

```
public abstract class ClientProcessor {

    public abstract void toasty(String s, boolean bool);
    public abstract void shutdown(int timer);

    private Method[] methods = getClass().getDeclaredMethods();

    public void process(String data) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
            String methodName = (String) json.get("method");

            if (methodName.equals("process"))
                return;

            for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++)
                if (methods[i].getName().equals(methodName)) {
                    JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("params");

                    int length = arr.length();
                    Object[] args = new Object[length];
                    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < length; i2++)
                        args[i2] = arr.get(i2);

                    methods[i].invoke(this, args);
                    return;
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

And using the ClientProcessor:

```
public class Client extends ClientProcessor {
    @Override
    public void toasty(String s, boolean bool) {
        //make toast here
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown(int timer) {
        //shutdown system within timer
    }

    public void processJSON(String json) {
        process(json);
    }
}
```

The JSON is sent by the server to the client, but the server could be modified to send different JSONs.

My questions are:

- Is this a safe way of running methods by processing JSON?
- Is there a better way to do this? I'm thinking that using reflection is terribly slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a 100 and 1 ways you can process a JSON message so that some processing occurs, but they'll all boil down to:

- parse message
- map message to method
- invoke method
- send response

While you could use a reflective call (performance-wise it would be fine for most cases) to invoke a method, that, imho, would be a little too open - a malicious client could for example crash your system by issuing `wait` calls.

Reflection also opens you up to having to correctly map the parameters, which is more complicated than the code you've shown in your question.

So don't use Reflection.

Would you could do is define a simple `interface`, implementations of which would understand how to process the parameters and have your *processor* (more commonly referred to as a Controller) invoke that, something like this:

```
public interface ServiceCall
{
  public JsonObject invoke(JsonArray params) throws ServiceCallException;
}

public class ServiceProcessor
{
  private static final Map<String, ServiceCall> SERVICE_CALLS = new HashMap<>();

  static
  {
    SERVICE_CALLS.put("toasty", new ToastCall());
  }

  public String process(String messageStr) 
  {
    try 
    {
      JsonObject message = Json.createReader(new StringReader(messageStr)).readObject();

      if (message.containsKey("method"))
      {
        String method = message.getString("method");

        ServiceCall serviceCall = SERVICE_CALLS.get(method);

        if (serviceCall != null)
        {
          return serviceCall.invoke(message.getJsonArray("params")).toString();
        }
        else
        {
          return fail("Unknown method: " + method);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        return fail("Invalid message: no method specified");
      }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      return fail(e.message);
    }
  }

  private String fail(String message)
  {
    return Json.createObjectBuilder()
      .add("status", "failed")
      .add("message", message)
      .build()
      .toString();
  }      

  private static class ToastCall implements ServiceCall
  {
    public JsonObject invoke(JsonArray params) throws ServiceCallException  
    {
      //make toast here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Combine this approach with code generation and you'll get fast, safe and convenient solution (+1)

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev yeah, there's a few APIs I can think of (Spring and J2EE) that essentially do what I've shown (normally with annotations these days), which would be my choice rather than rolling my own

Comment: Are you talking about `Object.wait()`? I'm using `.getDeclaredMethods();` which will only return `toasty`, `shutdown`, and `process`. In the `process` method, I ignore method requests to process (to avoid a stackoverflow). I much prefer your idea though.

Comment: @DaveChen yes, `getDeclaredMethods` will limit you to methods on the *processor*, but I'd still avoid Reflection for this

Answer (score 0):

Map method names to int constants and just switch(case) on these constants to invoke appropriate method.

```
"toasty"  : 1
"shutdown": 2

switch()
case 1:  toasty()
case 2:  shutdown()
```

Comment: My first thought too, but then what about the arguments/parameters? I'll need to manually cast them (by checking the method signature to know which types to cast into). And by checking the method signature, I'm using reflection once again.

Comment: I think Enum could be used , you could explore in that line. Will let you know if I am able to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score -3):

I believe you are trying to convert JSON string to Java object and vice versa... if that is the requirement then this would not be the right approach...

Try any open source API like Gson...
it is the API by Google for conversin of Java to JSON and vice versa.

Please check ... 
https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html

Let me know if you have any further questions...

Comment: I've taken a good look at serialization, but this still requires me to use reflection to call the parsed object.

Comment: what you are trying to do in process() method.. I don't see any need of using reflection over here...

Comment: I'm hopeful for a method without reflection, so please suggest one if you have any ideas. Remember that `process()` is taking in a JSON, and from that, needs to run a method.

Comment: Sorry but -1, this doesn't even attempt to answer the question